# Multiple condition search in Mongodb, but all of the search fields must have the ability to have the "any" option

Tags: node.js, reactjs, search, mongodb-query, mern

It is I again. Straight to the point:
I have 3 search fields (dropdown value selects) in my application to filter the products that will be shown to the user. And default should be "Any", so if every field has "any" chosen, it will just bring out every product from the database, and if only one of them has "any" chosen, that search criteria will be ignored and every product with any value of that field will be shown.
Sounds simple enough, but I just cannot get the right way to do it, so here I am here again, hoping for you to help me out here

Search Fields:

```
const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');
    const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');


    const handleChange1 = (event) => {
        setSubject(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleChange2 = (event) => {
        setStatus(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleChange3 = (event) => {
        setDistrict(event.target.value);
    };

<FormControl fullWidth>
                             <Select
                                value={subject}
                                label="subject"
                                onChange={handleChange3}
                                
                            >
                                <MenuItem value={''}>all</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt1'}>1</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt2'}>2</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt3'}>3</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
</FormControl>

<FormControl fullWidth>
                             <Select
                                value={status}
                                label="status"
                                onChange={handleChange3}
                                
                            >
                                <MenuItem value={''}>all</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt1'}>1</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt2'}>2</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt3'}>3</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
</FormControl>

<FormControl fullWidth>
                             <Select
                                value={district}
                                label="location"
                                onChange={handleChange3}
                                
                            >
                                <MenuItem value={''}>all</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt1'}>1</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt2'}>2</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'opt3'}>3</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
</FormControl>

<TutorList subject={subject} status={status} district={district} />
```

The page where the products load:

```
const TutorList = (props) => {
    const [tutors, setTutors] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTutors = async () => {
            const data = await axios.get(`/api/v1/user/search`, {
                params: {
                    subject: props.subject,
                    status: props.status,
                    district: props.district
                }
            })

            setTutors(data.data.users)
        }

        fetchTutors()
    }, [props]) 

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {tutors.map((tutor) => (
                ...
            ))}
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Backend:

```
exports.search = async (request, response, next) => {
    const subjectName = request.query.subject
    const statusName = request.query.status
    const districtName = request.query.district

    const users = await User.find({
        subject: subjectName, 
        district: districtName, 
        students: statusName
    })

    if (!users) {
        return next(
            new ErrorResponse(`Users with these parameters don't exist`, 404)
        )
    }

    response.status(200).json({ success: true, users: users })
}
```

Any ideas on that? It works perfectly fine if all the fields have values specified, but it stops working when one of the search fields is null (has option "any" chosen).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to filter the query parameter whose value is `''` or falsy value.

e.g. If `district` is `''`, it will be filtered.

```js
const request = {
  query: {
    subject: '1',
    status: 'ok',
    district: ''
  }
}

const query = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(request.query).filter(value => value[1]))

console.log(query)

// User.find(query)
```